# How can I give the Intellij compiler more heap space?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I make an Intellij project, I keep getting the following out of memory error.

I already increased my heap size in `idea.vmoptions`:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-ea
```

But I still get this error:

```
Information:The system is out of resources.
Information:Consult the following stack trace for details.
Information:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Information:    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position$LineMapImpl.build(Position.java:139)
Information:    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position.makeLineMap(Position.java:63)
Information:    at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.getLineMap(Scanner.java:1105)
Information:    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:512)
Information:    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:550)
Information:    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:804)
Information:    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:727)
Information:    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
Information:    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:279)
Information:    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:270)
Information:    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:69)
Information:    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:54)
Information:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Information:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
Information:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
Information:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Information:    at com.intellij.rt.compiler.JavacRunner.main(JavacRunner.java:71)
Information:Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Error:Compiler internal error. Process terminated with exit code 3
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Current version:

`Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Build, Execution, Deployment` | `Compiler` |
**Build process heap size**.

Older versions:

`Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Compiler` | `Java Compiler` | **Maximum heap size**.

Compiler runs in a separate JVM by default so IDEA heap settings that you set in `idea.vmoptions` have no effect on the compiler.

Comment: And a restart is required afterwards :)

Comment: I know this is slightly off-topic but might save someone some hair if they come across this.  I was having the same problem, but mine stemmed from when I was doing a `mvn install` in IntelliJ.  The solution was to modify the `Settings | Maven | Runner | **VM Options**`  I must have tried every other setting in there till I got that one right.  Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I can find it till ` Maximum heap size` Do i have to add it as a additional command line parameter?

Comment: @clankill3r try `Settings` | `Compiler` | `Build process heap size`.

Comment: For more recent versions of Intellij (mine is 2016.1.3) this parameter is called "Build process heap size (Mbytes)" and can be found in "Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler".

Comment: I was able to find it under Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | ActionScript & Flex Compiler --> Compiler heap size
Intellij Ultimate Edition 2018

Answer (score 116):

Since IntelliJ 2016, the location is **File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Build process heap size**.

[image]

Comment: I changed it to 2000 MB  but it still didn't work for me.

Comment: Worked like a charm, but I had to restart Intellij after changing the value

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem with Ant build (started by hand from IDEA GUI). In my case there was the right solution to right click on the Ant task, choose properties and set a higher value to "Maximum heap space (Mb):" and "Maximum stack space (Mb):" input fields.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To resolve this issue follow the below given steps-

1). In inteli Go to File> Setting Option and Search for Vm Option In the field of Vm Option for Importer give value -Xmx512m.
 [Intelij Setting Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJlDp.png)

2). Go to Control Pannel Select View by :Large icons then Go to Java one promp window will appear with name **java control pannel** then go to java 
[Java VM Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0HXb.png)

select view option.
[java view options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8lUW.png)

In Java Run time Environment Setting pass Run time Parameters as **-Xmx1024m**.

3). If above given options does not work then change the size of pom.xml

Comment: Why did you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51455242/revisions) out that link? Are you afraid of what happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50187283/4751173)?

Comment: i have given correct answer and i have given credit to another website but still i can see two downvotes to my answer.and answer which i have given is practically correct which i have faced and resolved it.

Comment: please let me know if i can give credit to another website.

Comment: That temporary downvote was from me. If you want to give credit, please link to the exact page where you found the information, not a list of tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

**GWT in Intellij 12**

FWIW, I was getting a similar error with my GWT application during '*Build | Rebuild Project*'.

This was caused by Intellij doing a full GWT compile which I didn't like because it is also a very lengthy process.

I disabled GWT compile by turning off the module check boxes under '***Project Structure | Facets | GWT***'.

Alternatively there is a '**Compiler maximum heap size**' setting in that location as well.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error while building my project using maven install command.

I was able to get rid of it by changing maven runner settings.

`Settings` | `Build, Execution, Deployment` | `Build Tools` | `Maven` | `Runner` | `VM options` to **-Xmx512m**

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was caused by the insufficient memory allocated to the "test" lifecycle of maven. It was fixed by adding `<argLine>-Xms3512m -Xmx3512m</argLine>` to:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>-Xms3512m -Xmx3512m</argLine>
```

Thanks @crazycoder for pointing this out (and also that it is not related to IntelliJ; in this case).

> If your tests are forked, they run in a new JVM that doesn't inherit Maven JVM options. Custom memory options must be provided via the test runner in pom.xml, refer to Maven documentation for details, it has very little to do with the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

On android studio 4.2 or newer  Arctic fox version you will option under appearance & behavior

1. Windows: file > settings > appearance & behavior > system settings > memory settings
2. Mac: file > preferences > appearance & behavior > system settings > memory settings

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEqBK.png

Answer (score 0):

I like to share a revelation that I had. When you build a project, Intellij Idea runs a java process that resides in its core(ex: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3\jbr\bin). The "build process heap size", as mentioned by many others, changes the heap size of **this** java process. However, the main java process is triggered later by the Idea's java process, hence have different VM arguments. I noticed that the max heap size of this process is 1/3 of the Idea's java process, while min heap is the half of max(1/6). To round up:

When you set 9g heap on "build process heap size" the actual heap size for the compiler is max 3g and min 1,5g. And no need for restart is neccessary.

PS: tested on version 2020.3

Answer (score 0):

[Link for IntelliJ documentation on setting custom parameters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#configure-platform-properties)

I was able to set the JVM options by going to the Run Debug configurations and setting the below value.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

There is a

> idea64.exe

starter in

> IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5\bin

so you can address more space.

Comment: This answer is to some extent correct, although is not in the context of question above. idea64.exe does give you more permgen memory, use idea64.exe if you're on 64bit OS. Found it useful coz 32bit idea.exe was crashing when running out of mem during build.