# IntelliJ Idea giving java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error even after increasing heap size

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, heap-memory

I have repeatedly got the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error when compiling my android project on IntelliJ Idea.

I increased my java heap space by following the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578062/how-to-increase-ide-memory-limit-in-intellij-idea-on-mac/13581526#13581526) however that didn't solve the problem. The funny thing is, at times my app will compile, and at other times the app will not compile due to the java heap space error. Even when I have made no changes to the app, it will compile at times and fail at times.

Any idea as to how I can solve this problem?

I am compiling an android project, could it be due to the large amount or resources (drawable hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, large-hdpi, large-xhdpi, large-xxhdpi) that I have? But then again, like I said it compiles at times and at times it doesn't. I'm down to making about 10 attempts to compile each time and luckily it will be successful once.

Here is the error:

> Internal error: (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError) Java heap space
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
>   java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.UnsyncByteArrayOutputStream.write(UnsyncByteArrayOutputStream.java:52)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:34)
>     at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.IOUtil.writeString(IOUtil.java:63)   at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.OneToManyPathsMapping$PathCollectionExternalizer.save(OneToManyPathsMapping.java:87)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.OneToManyPathsMapping$PathCollectionExternalizer.save(OneToManyPathsMapping.java:84)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage$1.append(AbstractStateStorage.java:103)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.doAppendData(PersistentHashMap.java:371)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.appendData(PersistentHashMap.java:358)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.appendData(AbstractStateStorage.java:101)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.OneToManyPathsMapping.appendData(OneToManyPathsMapping.java:50)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.SourceToOutputMappingImpl.appendOutput(SourceToOutputMappingImpl.java:50)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildOutputConsumerImpl.registerOutputFile(BuildOutputConsumerImpl.java:65)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidResourceCachingBuilder.runPngCaching(AndroidResourceCachingBuilder.java:126)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidResourceCachingBuilder.build(AndroidResourceCachingBuilder.java:48)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidResourceCachingBuilder.build(AndroidResourceCachingBuilder.java:32)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.BuildOperations.buildTarget(BuildOperations.java:100)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:744)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:770)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:702)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:523)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:314)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:179)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:129)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:220)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:112)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:132)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Go to Settings (Preferences on Mac) -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Maximum heap size (MB), and increase the size, then restart IntelliJ

Comment: If you user Android Studio this option in "Android compiler" section.

Comment: Setting has been moved to `Compiler` -> `Build proces heap size (MB)` in IntelliJ 17.2.3 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8581537/7193940

Comment: Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Shared build process heap size (Mbytes) in 2022.3.2

Answer (score 11):

I just had this problem today, and after doubling/quadrupling the heap sizes under File/Settings/Compiler/Java Compiler and .../Compiler/Android Compiler and it still wouldn't compile.

the value that finally fixed my problem was increasing the value called Compiler Process Heap Size (I doubled it but that probably isn't necessary), which can be found under File/Settings/Compiler

this solved the problem for me using Intellij version 12.1.5 (the latest right now)

also I realize that this thread is a bit old...

Comment: the reason I mention java compiler and android compiler is that it may be necessary to increase all of them, I have not tested that fact

Answer (score 6):

Intellij provides you with means to edit Application VM Options. Edit Configurations, I think, is what you are after. This setting is located in the top-right corner, or alternatively you can use shift-control-A "Edit configurations" you should see a dialog and one of the fields is VM Options. Here you can set your application-specific settings, i.e. -Xmx2048m.

Answer (score 4):

I increased the heap size and restarted the IntelliJ several times but *it did not work out for me* ...

I simply went to `build` menu and clicked on `rebuild project` and everything was **as good as before**

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was appearing following a "Reload Project" from the "Maven" section. It was throwing the `OutOfMemoryError` in the "Sync" tab of the "Build" window.

In this case, the proper settings to increase is the `VM options for importer` that you can find in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing. In my case, it was set to 512m which was too slow for my project with about 50 modules or so.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
This is my solution:

**Settings** -> **Build,execution,Deployment** -> **Compiler**

Upgrade

- Shared build process heap size
- User-local build process heap size (Mbytes)(overrides Shared sizes)

Comment: This worked for me. For me the issue was db connection was failing and retrying in loop. and hibernate dialect was not set