# Intellij slow after run completed

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I run a project localy and I monitor the memory that idea.exe holds.
The job finishes. java.exe is removed from the list. The memory is not getting smaller and intellij is slow and a bit unresponsive until a restart.
Then when I run again it it happens again.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Any number of factors could impact the speed of IntelliJ, like if your machine has enough memory.  In my experience, IntelliJ can easily consume close to 1 gigabyte of memory while I'm using it.  You may update the vmoptions as outlined here to attempt to increase the amount of memory allocated to IntelliJ when it starts.

[Why is IntelliJ 13 IDEA so slow after upgrading from version 12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545435/jetbrains-new-intellij-idea-13-slow#22508853)