# Tuning Idea Intellij 13.1

Tags: intellij-13

This question might have been asked several times before but the solutions didn't help. I am running a project of Grails 2.4.4 on Intellij 13.1, but when I run the application in the embedded Tomcat server (hit the run button at the top), it is performing very slow. I tried several ways of increasing the VM settings in idea.vmoptions, but none worked. Can anyone kindly suggest some way to improve the performance of the application?

Regards,
Anirban.

Comment: Upgrade to Intellij 14 at least.

Comment: Jared, I also installed Intellij 14 but its even more slower. So I continued using Intellij 13.1, but both are much slower. Can you kindly give some tips to tune the performance of Intellij 14? Then I'll continue using Intellij 14

Comment: Have you tried changing the Java version(from 1.6 to 1.7+)? How long have you used this? Have you tried "`File-> Invalidate Caches / Restart`"?

Comment: I am currently using Java 1.8. I have also tried Invalidate caches and restart but with no benefit. But I see all the plugins are enabled. Will disabling the unnecessary plugins help?

Comment: I am not sure. I do not have to. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545435/jetbrains-new-intellij-idea-13-slow. This has been ask on StackOverflow but with no clear answer.