# Configure Kotlin to an existing project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I created a kotlin new Kotlin project through intelliJ (https://github.com/dhananjay12/kotlin/tree/master/kotlin-basic) a while back. I then imported it into IntelliJ from a different machine.

There is no run option coming :
[image]

I tried to configure using Project SDK and Libraries, still, IntelliJ doesn't recognize it as a kotlin project.
[image]

[image]

NOTE- New project works completely fine

How do I configure an existing project to Kotlin?

What files need to be saved in git so that manually configuring IDE is not required?

Comment: Those files have main method, just right click on it and run the file.

Comment: As you can see from the first image, there is no run option coming. : (

Comment: Do you have the Kotlin plugin installed? I think it should come with current versions of IntelliJ now, but it's worth checking in Settings.

Comment: Yes, Kotlin plugin is installed. As I mentioned, new Kotlin projects works fine. I am struggling with importing existing project into intelliJ

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1) Right click the `src` folder

2) Mark directory as `Sources Root`

3) Will ask you to configure Java SDK and Kotlin Plugin for the module. Do it.

4) Run & enjoy

Comment: It worked.
Can you suggest a way so that it does this automatically? Did I missed a file or commit wrong project?

Comment: I think you should not add *.iml in gitignore file. Module level settings of IDE are saved there.

Comment: Thanks this did it. For some reason all root directories got lost when updating IntelliJ IDEA to 2019.2