# intellij very slow getting changes from disk

Tags: intellij-idea

I just checkout a new branch and even after 5 minute file system in intellij still didn't updated. Everything else also feels sluggish (click on files, click on a different line in intellij). I'm talking about 3 new files, not a big change. A few weeks ago was fine.

- Is not indexing anything
- Antivirus exlusions added to folders (used to ask me every time I open to add exclusions, seems like it forgets, I had to remove that setting to don't ask again)

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 x64 - Win 10 pro 64bit

I need to manuallly press "reload from disk" to get my changes now.

---

By chance I noticed a red thing blicking here

[image]

clicked on that and opeend

[image]

`java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi.impl.JSFileImpl cannot be cast to class com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlFile (com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi.impl.JSFileImpl is in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader @47a826eb; com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlFile is in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader @4f2410ac)`

I don't even use android..

Then I went to plugins and had hundreds of items selected. I unselected all that I don't need.

Answer (score 1):

`Settings` -> `Appearance & Behavior` -> `System Settings`

[image]

I had synchronize files on frame or editor tab activation - unchecked! that was the reason files didn't sync...

I figured out when I was reading this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965896/how-can-i-stop-indexing-intellij-idea#:~:text=You%20can%20stop%20synchronizing%2Findexing,frame%20or%20editor%20tab%20activation%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965896/how-can-i-stop-indexing-intellij-idea#:%7E:text=You%20can%20stop%20synchronizing%2Findexing,frame%20or%20editor%20tab%20activation%20).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there could be a lot of different things

1. In any such situation the first thing to do is "File->Invalidate Cache / Restart"

If this doesn't work

2. If you have a reasonably large project, you might exceed the Inotify Watches Limit (only on Linux systems). If this is the case follow the instruction [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit).

In short:

Add the following line to either /etc/sysctl.conf file or a new *.conf file (e.g. idea.conf) under /etc/sysctl.d/ directory:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

Then run this command to apply the change:

```
sudo sysctl -p --system
```