# How to make intellij idea run faster?

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

How can I make IDEA to run faster in Ubuntu? I am running it in a i7 thinkpad with 6 gigs of RAM.

Comment: And which kind of things exactly are slow?

Comment: In large projects (many modules and files) it is useful to exclude modules and folders that you do not use or modify. This reduces the "Scan files to index" time.

Answer (score 14):

Disable **all** unused plugins for example `Struts 2`, `Subversion Integration`, `UI Designer` if you don't have deal with them.

Also increase memory heap, for that I suggest you check following links:

- [Tuning IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/tuning-intellij-idea.html)
- [JetBrains' new intelliJ IDEA 13 slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22508853/2650174)

Comment: And [report performance problems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118-Reporting-performance-problems) if you have any. I would say that if any unused plugins cause problems, then they are broken and it needs to be reported.

Comment: Optimizer for IntelliJ has very low rating.  It force you to register or else it won't work.   So I do not recommend it.   (It has only 2 stars out of 5)

Comment: @mjlee You right. Looking for [comments about this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8056?pr=&ec=false&offset=0&max=15)   looks like this is bad idea to suggest it. Thanks for note I update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

help -> edit custom vm options -> change everything to:

```
--server
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-Xmn256m
-XX:MetaspaceSize=256m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2g
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Xverify:none
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseNUMA
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dide.no.platform.update=true
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off

-XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea.hprof
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).