# Does the performance of Intellij and related Jetbrains IDEs depend on JRE version?

Tags: java, performance, intellij-idea, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

I use many of the Jetbrains IDEs on a regular basis (specifically Intellij, Webstorm, Pycharm, and Rubymine) and have performance issues with all of them. I've tried all the usual performance recommendations such as increasing VM options, disabling plugins, exluding folders, using scopes, etc.

I was looking for other solutions and came across this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26337863/1220355. It seems as though performance of Intellij can be related to JRE version, though I haven't experienced this personally. Are Intellij and its sibling IDEs affected by what JRE is being used?