# IntelliJ IDEA Gradle Sync OutOfMemory

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I wonder how to increase heap size of Gradle Daemon process that IntelliJ IDEA uses to Sync project?

Current process uses **-Xms256m -Xmx512m**

I've already changed gradle-wrapper.properties file to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

My IntelliJ IDEA settings:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please try to select "gradle-wrapper.properties file" in "Use Gradle from" field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `gradle-wrapper.properties` is for the [wrapper scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) only. The `org.gradle.jvmarg` option doesn't belong in there.

Rather, put it in a `gradle.properties` file in the project root directory. See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) for more information.

Also be aware that `XX:MaxPermSize` is not supported since Java 8.

Lastly, you may need to also raise the heap used by IntelliJ itself. Check the current usage by right-clicking on the status bar and select Memory Indicator:

[image]

Notice the current and max heap in the bar to the right. If it is close to full, you can change the heap size under Help -> Change Memory Settings:

[image]

The memory settings you showed is for the IntelliJ compiler. But as you can see from the Gradle settings you also showed, you delegate the build to Gradle. So this has no effect.

Comment: Thank you, Bjørn ! I've created gradle.properties in project root directory and it solved problem!

Answer (score 0):

you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8581537) to give more heap memory to IntelliJ.

Hope you question is resolved.